# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setTitle'). for random cat picture command - Discord.js V14

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a random cat picture command using Discord.js V14. I've found a great api (https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search), but I keep getting an error
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setTitle')`. I'm using Axios, here is my code:

```
axios.get("https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search")
  .then((res) => {
    const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    console.log(res.data)
    .setTitle("Random Cat Image")
    .setImage(res.data.url)
    message.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    const error = String(err)
    message.reply("An error occured, sorry about that. Try again in a moment. Error: " + error + ". :face_with_monocle: ")
```

This is the data:

```
[{"id":"ba5","url":"https://cdn2.thecatapi.com/images/ba5.jpg","width":500,"height":340}]
```

Thank you!! :)

EDIT: I've taken out the `console.log(res.data)` because it was causing problems and I'm no longer getting the error, however, res.data.url is undefined. Which doesn't make sense since the data clearly has url.

Comment: `console.log(res.data)` returns `undefined`. The better question is why is it even there? If you _must_ log the data, move the `console.log()` up a line

Comment: I just had that there to see what the full data is, to debug. Taking it out now.

Comment: If you want to add logging lines, don't add them in the middle of chained expressions

Comment: I've taken it out, and I'm not getting the error anymore. However, the res.data.url is undefined. Which doesn't make any sense since the data clearly has url.

Comment: The data is an array. You want `res.data[0].url`

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that! Thank you, it works!

Answer (score 0):

The data is an array, so I would need to use `res.data[0].url`.
Thanks to Phil, for helping.